# CAML Query - Best practice

Tags: caml-query

I want to make sure the following CAML is best way to get a single record out of 100,000 items from a list. I know there are other versions where CAML goes through each record thus takes really long to return a single record.

```
<Query>
  <Lists>
    <List ID="GUID-HERE" />
  </Lists>
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Salescode" />
      <Value Type="Text">74558-7458</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
  <QueryOptions>
    <ViewAttributes Scope="Recursive" />
  </QueryOptions>
</Query>
```

Comment: Can't you split your content accross several lists? For exemple, one list per country/sell team/product family, ... and aggregate the result using either cross site query or search quey ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAML is the best way to go for quering the list . 
But since you have 100,000 your list will have to overcome the list throttling . The list throttling can be change in central admin ,but its better to do in code as mentioned below:

```
var query = new SPQuery();  
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><Value Type='Text'>Very Special    Item That I Need</Value></Eq></Where>";  
query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;
```

Apply query.ViewFields and get only specific fields from the list,Avoid the Recursive attribute.

Use query.Rowlimit properties and follow best practices for CAML .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure field `SalesCode`  is indexed.

If you are expecting only one record then apply `RowLimit`

Follow Microsoft's recommendation of maintaining large lists 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813(v=office.14).aspx